# Entity Data not available in hook_entity_insert

Tags: hooks

I have written hook_entity_insert for pdf file generation. Want the pdf file to be generated immediately after the entity is created.

```
function general_inspection_checklist_entity_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
    if($entity->getEntityTypeId() == "services_entity" && $entity->bundle() == "general_inspection_checklist"){      
        $entity_id = $entity->get('id')->getValue(); // Get Entity Id
        $link = $GLOBALS['base_url']."/entityprint/pdf/services_entity/".$entity_id[0]['value']; // Pdf URL
        $timestamp = date("Y-m-d_H:i:s");
        $data =  file_get_contents($link);
        //$filename = 'Booking_'.$timestamp.'_'.$entity_id[0]['value'].'.pdf';
        $filename = 'Booking_'.$entity_id[0]['value'].'.pdf';
        $path = 'public://bookings'; // Create a path
        if (file_prepare_directory($path, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY)) {
            $fileuri = 'public://bookings/'.$filename;
            $file = file_put_contents($fileuri, $data);
            $file = File::create([
                'uid' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
                'filename' => $filename,
                'uri' => $fileuri,
                'status' => 1,
            ]);
            $file->save();
        }
       $entity_name = $entity->get('name')->getValue(); // Get Entity Name
        // Load Service Entity based on ID
        $serviceentity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('services_entity')->loadByProperties(['id' => $entity_name[0]['value']]);
        $serviceentity = reset($serviceentity);
        if(!empty($serviceentity)){  
            //$field_booking_sheet = $serviceentity->get('field_booking_sheet')->getValue();
            // if(!empty($field_booking_sheet)){
            //     ksm($field_booking_sheet);
            // }
            // else{
                $serviceentity->set('field_booking_sheet', ['target_id' => $file->id()]);
                $serviceentity->save();
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a link which will be available only after the entity is saved in database. But the `hook_entity_insert` is called before the entity it is completely saved in the dataase. So, the PDF link won't be available.

```
$link = $GLOBALS['base_url']."/entityprint/pdf/services_entity/".$entity_id[0]['value']; // Pdf URL
```

You can use `drupal_register_shutdown_function` in such cases. You can put your PDF related code in another function and just register it here with `drupal_register_shutdown_function`. It's basically telling drupal that, after the `entity_insert()` function has run completely, execute this block of code.

```
function general_inspection_checklist_entity_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
        if($entity->getEntityTypeId() == "services_entity" && $entity->bundle() == "general_inspection_checklist"){      
            $entity_id = $entity->get('id')->getValue(); // Get Entity Id

            drupal_register_shutdown_function('YOUR_CUSTOM_FUNCTION', $entity_id);

        }
    }


function YOUR_CUSTOM_FUNCTION($entity_id){
    //Your STUFF
    $link = $GLOBALS['base_url']."/entityprint/pdf/services_entity/".$entity_id[0]['value']; // Pdf URL
    $timestamp = date("Y-m-d_H:i:s");
    $data =  file_get_contents($link);
    //$filename = 'Booking_'.$timestamp.'_'.$entity_id[0]['value'].'.pdf';
    $filename = 'Booking_'.$entity_id[0]['value'].'.pdf';
    $path = 'public://bookings'; // Create a path
    if (file_prepare_directory($path, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY)) {
        $fileuri = 'public://bookings/'.$filename;
        $file = file_put_contents($fileuri, $data);
        $file = File::create([
            'uid' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
            'filename' => $filename,
            'uri' => $fileuri,
            'status' => 1,
        ]);
        $file->save();
    }

}
```